# Period of a sequence with python pycogent

Tags: python, algorithm

While working with a problem, I faced with determining the period of a sequence in Python. I faced with the cogent [library](http://pycogent.org/examples/period_estimation.html)

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

- How can use the cogent library to determine the period of my sequence?
- What are exactly the `pwr` and `period` values returned from these `DFT` or `auto_corr`.

Comment: Use Fourrier analysis.

Comment: any example somewhere?